# Why does ModelBuilder with kriging give ERROR 001000 Z value field does not exist?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, kriging

I've built a model which interpolates series of data by IDW method and it works well. But when I tried to change method of interpolation to kriging I encountered some problems with using Z value field as a variable.
Here are some pictures that may help to explain my problem:
how the data look like: http://imageshack.us/a/img22/4167/l4th.jpg
 IDW version: http://imageshack.us/a/img221/1879/qegc.png
I'm using 'For' iterator and variable for Z value field 'a%Value%' so every iteration is using next data field as Z values. And values of the iterator are preconditions to interpolation. It's is basically the same model in both versions but I don't know why the variable isn't working with kriging. When I open the Kriging tool I've got this error in Z value field:

> ERROR 001000 Z value field: Field a%Value% does not exist

but in the IDW version it works well. Any ideas?

Comment: Obvious dumb question, your for loop is it looping over the correct range of values and not starting at Zero? Your example image suggests it should be over a range of 1 to 6

Comment: I'm starting from 1. The thing is that this model with IDW interpolation works but when I change the method of interpolation to Kriging I've got errors. But entire model is basically the same except method of interpolation.

Comment: Sounds like you've found (yet another) bug. May be worth logging it with ESRI.

Comment: Thanks for response. It looks like it is a bug indeed. Anyway I figured out that I was using IDW interpolation from Geostatistical Analyst toolbox and then I tried to use kriging form Spatial Analyst. When I changed IDW method from Geostatistical to the one from Spatial Analyst toolbox I've encountered the same problem with iteration so I assume that this method of iteration only works with tools from the Geostatistical Analyst.

Comment: It might help to know that SA and GA are *completely different,* having been written independently at different times by different non-interacting groups. It would be wise to stick to one or the other during a calculation, if at all possible.